# Recursion and functions

Tags: function

Thanks for helping everyone. I will continue looking at it so I can better understand! I am still struggling with recursion but I will study it more. Thanks again for all your time and effort for trying to help me
- /

```
       int countEven(int arr[i]){
       //I'm not sure what to do here... how to fix it...
       int evens = 0;
       if(arr[i] <= 0) return 0; //base case

       while(arr[i] > 0){
       int digit = arr[i]%10; //get the last digit
       if(digit%2 == 0){
          evens = evens+1;
        }
        arr[i] = arr[i]/10;
        }
        cout << evens;
         }
            }
        }
         int main(){
             cout << "Part A:\n";
             int arr[3] = { 5050155, 5, 707070 };
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
             cout << "countEven(" << arr[i] << ") = " << countEven(arr[i]) << endl;
             cout << "removeEven(" << arr[i] << ") = " << removeEven(arr[i]) << endl;
             cout << "hasEven(" << arr[i] << ") = ";


 if (hasEven(arr[i])) cout << "Yes" << endl;
         else cout << "No" << endl;
         printStarDigit(arr[i]);
         cout << endl << endl;
         }
         cout << "Part B:\n";
         int a[4] = { 7, 2, 8, 3 };
         int b[5] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
         cout << "The range of array a is " << range(a, 4) << endl;
         cout << "The range of array b is " << range(b, 5) << endl;
         reverse(a, 4);
         reverse(b, 5);
         cout << "Array a reversed: ";
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
         cout << a[i] << " ";
         cout << endl;
         cout << "Array b reversed: ";
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
         cout << b[i] << " ";
         cout << endl;
         return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Do you know what a recursive function is; or how to pass arguments?

Comment: Yes! You need a base case and then you have to call the function in the function itself

Comment: I'm unsure of how to pass arguments of an array which is causing me to be confused

Comment: Without worrying about the recursion, how would you go about counting the number of even digits in a value if you had to do it by hand?

Comment: You would need to have a counter for the even digits. Also to read each digit individually by using %10

Comment: @Lizzy you're trying to pass an array of variable size to a function - so I'd suggest that you pass a pointer to an int and a size - for example `{int a[4] = {}; recursive(a, 4);}` and then `void recursive(const int*, int size){}`  Note that it's probably not going to return void...

Comment: @UKMonkey can you explain what that means? This is my first time working with arrays so I'm a little confused

Comment: Just a hint: the count of even digit in 0 is 0 and the count of even digit in n>0 is the count of even digits in n/10 + 1 if n%10 is even. Write that in C++ to have your recursive function.

Comment: @UKMonkey No, the `main` function is passing a single `int` value to that function (which is correct), so modifying the function to take a pointer and a size is the wrong approach.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Could you explain a little more, please? I'm confused... (ps I'm sorry everyone... I'm just having a hard time understanding this new topic so I'm sorry if I'm being annoying)

Comment: @hvd - my mistake - misread 'reverse' as 'recurse' ;)

Comment: @Lizzy Can you write in C++ a function that takes an int parameter and returns this number divided by ten? I assume yes. Then can you write a function (lets's call it f) that takes an int parameter (say n)  and that return 1 if that parameter is 0 ; else examine n%2 if it is 0, the last digit is even, else it is odd. So what about returning  (1 - n%2) + f(n/10)?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int countEven(int arr[i]){
> ```

Parameters must have simple names, and do not need to be identical to the expressions passed in. `arr[i]` is not a valid name. A simple name to use here is `n`.

> ```
> //I'm not sure what to do here... how to fix it...
> int evens = 0;
> if(arr[i] <= 0) return 0; //base case
> ```

This base case is wrong for two reasons. Firstly, you treat all negative integers as the base case, but `-202020` has six even digits. Secondly, you return the wrong value: `0` has one even digit, but you return zero.

A possible base case could be `n > -10 && n < 10` (single digit number). I'll let you figure out the expression to return for that base case.

> ```
> while(arr[i] > 0){
> ```

If your task is to write a recursive function, then you shouldn't use a loop here. Instead, see below.

> ```
> int digit = arr[i]%10; //get the last digit
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> arr[i] = arr[i]/10;
> ```

This is a correct way of obtaining the last digit, and everything other than the last digit.

> ```
> if(digit%2 == 0)
> ```

This is a correct way of determining whether the last digit is even.

Now, you need to combine what you have, by observing that the count of even digits is equal to "1 if the last digit is even, else 0", plus the count of even non-last digits. The goal of the exercise is to get you to write "the count of even non-last digits" as `countEven(n / 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

See these code snippets.

```
int countEven(int n, bool first_time = true){
    static int total ;
    int num =n;

    if (first_time)
    {
        total = 0;
    }

    if (num <= 9) {
        return num % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    int temp = num - (num / 10) * 10;
    num = num / 10;
    total += temp % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    countEven(num,false);

    return total;
}

int removeEven(int n){
    int result = 0;
    /*TODO*/
    return result;
}

bool hasEven(int n){
    return countEven(n);
}

void printStarDigit(int* arr){
    /*TODO*/
}

int range(int* arr, int n){
    int result = *arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (result < *(arr + i))  result = *(arr + i);
    }
    return result;
}

void reverse(int* arr, int n){
    int* temp = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(temp + i) = *(arr + i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(arr + i) = *(temp + n - 1 - i);
    }

    delete[] temp;
}
```

Main implementation :

```
int main() {
    cout << "Part A:\n";
    int arr[3] = { 5050155, 5, 707070 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "countEven(" << arr[i] << ") = " << countEven(arr[i]) << endl;
        cout << "removeEven(" << arr[i] << ") = " << removeEven(arr[i]) << endl;
        cout << "hasEven(" << arr[i] << ") = ";


        if (hasEven(arr[i])) cout << "Yes" << endl;
        else cout << "No" << endl;
        printStarDigit(arr + i);
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << "Part B:\n";
    int a[4] = { 7, 2, 8, 3 };
    int b[5] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    cout << "The range of array a is " << range(a, 4) << endl;
    cout << "The range of array b is " << range(b, 5) << endl;
    reverse(a, 4);
    reverse(b, 5);
    cout << "Array a reversed: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Array b reversed: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]